# font: Lucida Grande Unicode - does it exist?

Tags: fonts

I used Lucida Grande Unicode in photoshop to design my graphics. Now I'm trying to xhtml it.

The problem is that, when I use css ->  font:1em Lucida Grande Unicode nothing happens... I don't see right font, but when I use only Lucida Grande it works fine.

What is the problem? Am I calling this font incorrectly?

Btw, I'm on MAC. And I use firefox/firebug.

p.s. In photoshop Luida Grande and Lucida Grande Unicode look different, small letters have different height. So I absolutely need Unicode version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's Lucida Grande, Lucida Sans, and Lucida Sans Unicode. I've never heard of "Lucida Grande Unicode"—which doesn't make much sense since Lucida Grande already supports Unicode characters.

Also, you shouldn't be using Lucida Grande anything on a webpage unless you're rasterizing it or embedding it as a web font. Only Lucida Sans is a cross-platform web font.